# Socket.io express different routing

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to use Socket.IO on the latest express version but without success.
I want to use the Socket.IO functionality on the specific js file with "router" and not with "app.js", the global one.

In addition, I want the server side to be different page from the client side.

Here's my code:

1. Server side, a file named "addPost.js" which located at the "routes" folder:

   ```
   router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     io.on('connection', function (socket) {
       socket.emit('news',
           {
               hello: 'world'
           });

       socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
           console.log(data);
       });
     });
     res.render('addPost');
   });
   ```
2. Client side, a file named "index.ejs" which located at the "views" folder and it's not related somehow with the "addPost.js":

   ```
   <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');

     socket.on('news', function (data) {
         console.log(data);
         socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
     });
   </script>
   ```

How can I connect between them??

Comment: Placing io.on('connection'... inside router.get.... makes no sence. io.on(...) only needs to be run once and you run it every time someone hits your route. You should separate socket logic from router since they are not related, althought they might use same data.

Comment: @Molda, can you elaborate on your comment? Specifically, separating socket logic from router? I have ran into a similar problem, where I am not sure how to access the socket on other routes once I have set up the connection in server.js. Ideally, there should be a res.socket object to emit events to the client, but I have yet to find such functionality.

Comment: @JonathanKempf Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to make socket listen to server's port. smth like this in addPost.js:

```
   function listenServer(){
io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
}
```

if you want to do it not in your app file you should to send link to your server to socket. Something like this in your app.js:

```
    var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    log.info('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
var socket = require('addPost.js');
socket.listenServer(server);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put io.on inside router
do simply this

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('addPost');
  // after you render the page
  // client will connect to socket
  // or if you want to send news along with this request do something like
  getNews(function(err, news){          
      res.render('addPost', {news: news});
      // obviously you need to render the news in your view
  });
});  



io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // now after the client has recieved page from res.render
  // client will connect and can ask for news
  socket.on('getNews', function () {
      // your logic to get news
      getNews(function(err, news){          
          if(!err) socket.emit('news', news);
      });
  });

  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
  });
});
```

in client script

```
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');
  //ask for news
  socket.emit('getNews');

  socket.on('news', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Hope it helps.